MSTest Serilog Console issue
I have a library C# project which has services written. This is using serilog and able to print serilogs on console during normal execution. But when I am using same library within my functional test cases using MSTest then serilogs are not getting printed on console.
Tried using serilog package with functional tests and setting sink to console and file too but that's not working. Neither logs are coming to console nor to file while running functional test.
Using below in appsetting.json in both library and function test project.
    "Serilog": {
      "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "System": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
            "path": "info/logs.txt"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Enrich": [
        "FromLogContext",
        "WithMachineName",
        "WithThreadId"
      ]
    }


check whether Console.WriteLine in the test routes to where you want it. Then wire the log emission explicitly. Alternately, consider using one of the various serilog sinks that output to Debug.WriteLine etc

I created, published and use my own NuGet Package for this. It doesn't create a serilog sink but doesn't stop you from using it side-by-side
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Walter.Extensions.Logging.MSTest/2024.8.5.1010
To integrate it I do:
namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private static ServiceProvider? _serviceProvider;


        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddMsUnitTestLogger(context, LogLevel.Debug);
            _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup()
        {
            _serviceProvider?.Dispose();
        }



        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException))]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            if (_serviceProvider is null) Assert.Fail("Class setup failed");

            // Get non-generic ILogger
            var logger = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
            logger.LogInformation("This is a non-generic test log message.");

            // Get generic ILogger<>
            var genericLogger = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<UnitTest1>>();
            genericLogger.LogInformation("This is a generic test log message.");

            try
            {
                var willFail= File.Open("x:\\dirNotfound\\and\\file\\doesNotExist.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                genericLogger.LogException(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

Any class that uses dependency injection to use ILogger or ILogger will generate its output into the test summary.
The line:
serviceCollection.AddMsUnitTestLogger(context, LogLevel.Debug);

allows you to set the messages you like to see.
Setting it to:
serviceCollection.AddMsUnitTestLogger(context, LogLevel.Error);
Will only output exceptions or higher.
Hope it helps
